# How reuse formatted Doctrine 2 with QueryBuilder formatted query in other query

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder, doctrine-query

I have formatted query with doctrine query builder. It is kind of complicated because in that query there are some my own defined doctrine functions and doctrine extensions. Also very important to mention that this query using filter which is require some preselected values. The problem is when i want to count records from that query. Of course i Can write count(results), but it is very bad for performance.

I try to create new sql query with my own predefined query as source, but the problem that parameters are not injected.

Query which is formatted and which result i want to count :

```php
private function getCategoriesQuery(Filter $filter = null, Sort $sort = null, Pagination $pagination = null)
{
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.id as id')
            ->addSelect('c.title as title')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(c.updationDate, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S\') as updationDate')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(c.creationDate, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S\') as creationDate')
            ->addSelect('coalesce(sum(r.amount), 0.00) as total')
            ->addSelect('round(AveragePerMonth(coalesce(sum(r.amount), 0.00), c.creationDate, CURRENT_DATE()), 2) as averagePerMonth')
            ->leftJoin('c.records', 'r')
            ->groupBy('c.id')
            ->andWhere('c.user = :user')->setParameter('user', $this->user);

        if ($filter) $this->applyFilters($filter, $qb);
        if ($sort) $this->applySort($sort, $qb);
        if ($pagination) $this->applyPagination($pagination, $qb);

        return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

I tried:

```php
public function countUserCategories(Filter $filter = null)
{
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $sql = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('select count(*) from ('.$this->getCategoriesQuery($filter)->getSQL().') as src', $rsm);
        return $sql->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

I expected the answer if there is possibility to combine these queries and if there is possiblity how i can do that. Thanks

ApplyFilter method:

```php
private function applyFilters(Filter $filter, QueryBuilder $qb)
{
        if ($filter->getCategories()) {
            $qb->andWhere('c.id IN(:categories)')->setParameter('categories', $filter->getCategories());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndDate()) {
            $qb->andWhere('r.date <= :endDate')->setParameter('endDate', $filter->getEndDate());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartDate()) {
            $qb->andWhere('r.date >= :startDate')->setParameter('startDate', $filter->getStartDate());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartTotal() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('total >= :startTotal')->setParameter('startTotal', $filter->getStartTotal());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndTotal() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('total <= :endTotal')->setParameter('endTotal', $filter->getEndTotal());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartAveragePerMonth() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('averagePerMonth >= :startAveragePerMonth')->setParameter('startAveragePerMonth', $filter->getStartAveragePerMonth());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndAveragePerMonth() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('averagePerMonth <= :endAveragePerMonth')->setParameter('endAveragePerMonth', $filter->getEndAveragePerMonth());
        }
}
```

Suggested way to solve this issue but return response : `The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().`

```php
public function countUserCategories(Filter $filter = null)
{
        return (clone $this->getCategoriesQueryBuilder($filter))
            ->resetDQLPart('select')
            ->select('COUNT(c)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I make this work by using SQL query builder

Query builder creation

```php
private function getCategoriesQueryBuilder(Filter $filter = null, Sort $sort = null, Pagination $pagination = null)
{
        $qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.id AS id')
            ->addSelect('c.title AS title')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(c.updation_date, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S\') AS updationDate')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(c.creation_date, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S\') AS creationDate')
            ->addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(r.amount), 0.00) AS total')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(r.amount), 0.00) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(calendar.date, \'%Y-%m\'))), 2)
                                FROM calendar as calendar
                                WHERE calendar.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(c.creation_date, \'%Y-%m-%d\') AND DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), \'%Y-%m-%d\')) 
                                AS averagePerMonth')
            ->from('category', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c', 'record', 'r', 'r.category_id = c.id')
            ->join('c', 'users', 'u', 'u.id = c.user_id')
            ->where('u.id = :userId')->setParameter('userId', $this->user->getId())
            ->groupBy('c.id');

        if ($sort) $this->applySort($sort, $qb);
        if ($pagination) $this->applyPagination($pagination, $qb);
        if ($filter) $this->applyFilter($filter, $qb);

        return $qb;
}
```

Filter

```php
private function applyFilter(Filter $filter, QueryBuilder $qb)
{
        if ($filter->getCategories()) {
            $qb->andWhere('c.id IN(:categories)')->setParameter('categories', $filter->getCategories());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndDate()) {
            $qb->andWhere('r.date <= :endDate')->setParameter('endDate', $filter->getEndDate());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartDate()) {
            $qb->andWhere('r.date >= :startDate')->setParameter('startDate', $filter->getStartDate());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartTotal() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('total >= :startTotal')->setParameter('startTotal', $filter->getStartTotal());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndTotal() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('total <= :endTotal')->setParameter('endTotal', $filter->getEndTotal());
        }

        if ($filter->getStartAveragePerMonth() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('averagePerMonth >= :startAveragePerMonth')->setParameter('startAveragePerMonth', $filter->getStartAveragePerMonth());
        }

        if ($filter->getEndAveragePerMonth() !== null) {
            $qb->andHaving('averagePerMonth <= :endAveragePerMonth')->setParameter('endAveragePerMonth', $filter->getEndAveragePerMonth());
        }
}
```

Count

```php
public function countUserCategories(Filter $filter = null)
{
        $subQuery = $this->getCategoriesQueryBuilder($filter);
        $params = $subQuery->getParameters();

        return $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('COUNT(src.id)')
            ->from('(' . $subQuery . ')', 'src')
            ->setParameters($params)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchColumn(0);
}
```

Fetch

```php
public function findUserCategories(Filter $filter = null, Sort $sort = null, Pagination $pagination = null)
{
        return $this->getCategoriesQueryBuilder($filter, $sort, $pagination)->execute()->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the original query as subquery to get count.

```php
public function countUserCategories(Filter $filter = null)
{
    $querysub = $this->getCategoriesQuery($filter);

    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();

    $query
        ->select('COUNT(*)')
        ->from('(' . $querysub->getSQL() . ')', 'ttt');

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($querysub->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $query->setParameter($i++, $parameter->getValue(), $parameter->getType());
    }

    $count = $query->execute()->fetchColumn(0);

    return $count;
}
```

This will work if parameters are set in order with their appearance in query.

Comment: It is can not be done, because there is difference in count after filter ```if ($filter) $this->applyFilters($filter, $qb);```, which is filter depends on selected fields.

Comment: `QueryBuilder` for `count` also has all these filters. It's a copy of original `QueryBuilder`. Did you try?

Comment: Yes i try. I get ```The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().```

Comment: Put you new code in original post. I suppose you have some error. It's impossible to get multiple rows in this case.

Comment: I updated my original post and add filter method. You see that there are filters by averagePerMonth and total selected fields which are calculated in selected statements.

Comment: Everything should work, `ApplyFilter ` just adds `where` statements, nothing more.

Comment: Try `->select('COUNT(c.id)')`

Comment: I change getSingleScalarResult to getResult to see what query returns. So response was array of 18 arrays which have 0 => 128

Comment: The same with `->select('COUNT(c.id)')`

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: I get error ```[Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near 'FROM (SELECT': Error: Subquery is not supported here```